# Three.js - DOMException: "The operation is insecure." - most likely cross domain issue

Tags: three.js, cross-domain

I have implemented a three.js viewer for my panoramic pictures a couple of years ago and now that I'm moving my site to another location, I have an issue with Three.js not willing to load anymore.

Error message in the console: 
DOMException: "The operation is insecure."

Here is the html part I'm using:

```
<div class="article-pano-gallery" style="display:table">
<img onclick="init('https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2017/05/photo-panoramique-360-Catane.jpg')" class="article-gallery-image pano-image" data-srcset="https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2017/05/photo-panoramique-360-Catane.jpg" src="https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2017/05/photo-panoramique-360-Catane-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150">
</div>
```

And for the JS part:

```
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r84/three.min.js"></script>    
<script>
var camera, scene, renderer;
var isUserInteracting = false,
onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
phi = 0, theta = 0;

function init(full_image) 
   {
       var container, mesh;
    container = document.getElementById( 'background-section' );
    document.getElementById( 'background-section') .style.display='block';
    document.getElementById( 'pano-loading-section') .style.display='block';
    document.getElementById( 'close') .style.display='block';
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
    camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
    // invert the geometry on the x-axis so that all of the faces point inward
    geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( full_image )
        } );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth*0.95, window.innerHeight*0.95 );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onPointerStart, false );
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onPointerMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onPointerUp, false );
document.addEventListener( 'wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onPointerStart, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onPointerMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchend', onPointerUp, false );

document.addEventListener( 'dragover', function ( event ) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}, false );

document.addEventListener( 'dragenter', function () 
{
    document.body.style.opacity = 0.5;
}, false );

document.addEventListener( 'dragleave', function () 
{
    document.body.style.opacity = 1;
}, false );

document.addEventListener( 'drop', function ( event ) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
        material.map.image.src = event.target.result;
        material.map.needsUpdate = true;
    }, false );
    reader.readAsDataURL( event.dataTransfer.files[ 0 ] );
        document.body.style.opacity = 1;
    }, false );
            //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    document.getElementById( 'pano-loading-section') .style.display='none';
    animate();
}

function onWindowResize() 
{
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth*0.95, window.innerHeight*0.95 );
}

function onPointerStart( event ) 
{
    isUserInteracting = true;
    var clientX = event.clientX || event.touches[ 0 ].clientX;
    var clientY = event.clientY || event.touches[ 0 ].clientY;
    onMouseDownMouseX = clientX;
    onMouseDownMouseY = clientY;
    onMouseDownLon = lon;
    onMouseDownLat = lat;
}

function onPointerMove( event ) 
{
    if ( isUserInteracting === true ) 
        {
            var clientX = event.clientX || event.touches[ 0 ].clientX;
            var clientY = event.clientY || event.touches[ 0 ].clientY;
            lon = ( onMouseDownMouseX - clientX ) * 0.1 + onMouseDownLon;
            lat = ( clientY - onMouseDownMouseY ) * 0.1 + onMouseDownLat;
        }
}

function onPointerUp() 
{
    isUserInteracting = false;
}

function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) 
{
    var fov = camera.fov + event.deltaY * 0.05;
    camera.fov = THREE.Math.clamp( fov, 10, 75 );
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    update();
}

function update() 
{
    if ( isUserInteracting === false ) 
        {
            lon += 0.1;
        }
    lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );
    camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
    camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
    camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
    camera.lookAt( camera.target );
            /*
            // distortion
            camera.position.copy( camera.target ).negate();
            */
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


</script>
```

I was using the same script on another domain for images and it was working well but now that I have moved, it doesn't work anymore.

I suppose it has something to do with cross domain but I don't see where exactly. I have tried a local version of the JS file and it's the same issue.

The error in the JS occurs on line 121. Here is the full text as requested below:

```
DOMException: "The operation is insecure." three.js:121:396
texImage2D https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:121
n https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:97
setTexture2D https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:181
hf https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:7
upload https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:343
G https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:147
renderBufferDirect https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:165
n https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:134
render https://wp.laurentwillen.be/js/three.js:180
update https://wp.laurentwillen.be/circuits/circuit-italie/catane/?bb:1679
animate https://wp.laurentwillen.be/circuits/circuit-italie/catane/?bb:1659
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include the full text of the error message, including any info like what was trying to be retrieved when the error occurred.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks, I have added the information to my post.

Comment: Is this in Firefox by any chance? Have you tested it in other browsers?

Comment: @TheJim01 yes it was Firefox but I doesn't work on Chrome but there I have another error message (Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.)

Comment: Old question I know but did anybody found a solution to this issue? I have the same problem even if the image that is loaded into the canvas has the proper CORS flag access-control-allow-origin: *

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a CORS issue. I recommend you get yourself acquainted with [how modern browsers handle cross-domain requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

My best guess is that your `images.laurentwillen.be` server isn't configured to allow delivering assets to other domains. This is a safety feature so other people don't steal your bandwidth (you probably wouldn't want 1000s of sites freeloading by using images hosted on your server).

There are 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Host the images in the same domain where they're being requested.
2. Figure out how to let your server allow delivery of images to the domain where you're using them. The way to achieve this depends on the type of server you're running and you'll have to do some digging to figure out how to configure it, so solution 1 would be easiest.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense but wp.laurentwillen.be or www.laurentwillen.be can access images from images.laurentwillen.be. It is only when a picture is loaded through Three.js that it doesn't work. It's like three.js was calling my image from an external domain.

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with bandwidth. You can use images from other servers just fine without CORS permission and use up all their bandwidth. CORS wrt images is only about seeing the pixels inside the canvas. You can put `<img src="https://example.com/no-cors-permission.jpg">` and it will show up on your page just fine. You can even draw it into a canvas. You just can't read that canvas nor use it or the image in WebGL without permission.